# SQL Loader Error - SQL*Loader-503: Error appending extension to file ()

Tags: unix, sed, sql-loader

I am trying to load a bunch of Java files into a staging table using SQL Loader. I keep getting the subject line error and I'm not sure why.

My executable file that I am trying to run looks like this.

```
for i in `find <files in certain directory.java>`
do
echo "File name = ${i}"
COMMAND='sed'; ARG='s/XXXX/${i}/'
echo $COMMAND  '; '  $ARG
cat test_load.ctl | $COMMAND "$ARG" > test_load_2.ctl
sqlldr <user>/<password> control=test_load_2.ctl log=<file_name>.log
done
```

My test_load.ctl file looks like this:

I'm trying to replace the XXXX INFILE with the looped through files in the Java directory above.

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'XXXX'
BADFILE '/<directory>/<filename>.bad'
DISCARDFILE '/<directory>/<filename>.dsc'
APPEND INTO TABLE "<SCHEMA>"."<TABLE_NAME>"
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
 id sequence (1, 1),
 raw_string position (1:4000) char(4000),
 file_name,
 dir_path,
 load_date sysdate,
 line_number sequence (1, 1)
)
```

My test_load_2.ctl file looks like this:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE '${i}'
BADFILE '/<directory>/<filename>.bad'
DISCARDFILE '/<directory>/<filename>.dsc'
APPEND INTO TABLE "<SCHEMA>"."<TABLE_NAME>"
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
 id sequence (1, 1),
 raw_string position (1:4000) char(4000),
 file_name,
 dir_path,
 load_date sysdate,
 line_number sequence (1, 1)
)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
SQL*Loader-503: Error appending extension to file ()
Additional information: 7217
```

I'm pretty sure there is an issue with the INFILE parameter in the test_load_2.ctl file, but I am not 100% certain how to fix this?

Also I'm probably doing something wrong in the executable file as well.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No variable expansion is going to happen in the control file.  Specify the INFILE on the commandline instead using the DATA argument.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_params.htm#SUTIL004